# Android PendingIntent and how I should handle its action in the main Activity

Tags: android

I've been trying for a couple of days to create a notification (with a button) on Android and handle its action on the main activity. Everything works just fine, but there's an issue I can't figure out:

When the activity is opened by the `PendingIntent`, it shows a dialog after checking if the action is the one from the notification `(getIntent().getAction().equals("action"))`.

So far so good, but when the user clicks on recent apps and then gets back to the activity, the action is processed again.

I tried doing the check on the `onCreate()` method, but it's being called every time since the activity is flagged as `noHistory=true` in the Manifest.

Because of this, the activity is re-created every time so I can't use a boolean flag to show the dialog only once either. I thought of using a broadcast in the `PendingIntent` but I'll need to launch the main activity anyway (this is a business requirement).

Even if I remove the `noHistory` attribute, when pressing the back button, finish() is called and the activity is destroyed, but it can be re-run from the recent apps menu and everything starts over with the notification action in place.

Could anyone please give me a hint on how to handle this? Please keep in mind that the action validation method is called from the `onCreate()` and the latter is being called every time the app leaves foreground, because of the `noHistory` and also when the user clicks the back button (the `finish()` call is made) and the `onCreate()` will be called again next time the user brings the app to foreground from the recent menu (I should not disable it since it's required by the app).

To make myself even clearer, the issue is that the user keeps seeing the dialog every time the app goes to background and gets chosen from the recent apps menu or the recent apps button is clicked and the user choose my activity.

Answer (score 0):

A dirty way would be to store the state (flag) on disk and check on startup whether to fire the dialog or not.
If you wanna go that route, I'd recommend **SharedPreferences** https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html.